# vimperator: how to select a completion with a number?

Tags: vimperator

Can I choose a completion with a number if, for example, the 6th one is my desired completion?
And how can I scrol down a page of the completion list?

Answer (score 2):

Completions in the command line are selected with the `Tab` key. Just keep hitting `Tab`!